# TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby

Trying to decode a bin file in ruby script but after running the script I get the following error test.rb:57:in `read': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError) from script:57:in`'

Any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

```
require 'bindata'

class Decode < BinData::Record # size 4+
  uint32le :record_count
  array    :records, :type => :cube_main_bin_record, :initial_length  => :record_count
end


begin
  f = ARGV[0] unless ARGV[0].nil?
  bin = File.read(f)

  Decode.read(bin).records.each_with_index do |rec, num|
    puts "Record #{num} #{rec.to_binary_s.length}"
    p rec
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `File.read` requires a string parameter and `f` defaults to nil when you invoke the script without a command line argument

```
f = ARGV[0] unless ARGV[0].nil?     # f defaults to nil when ARGV[0] is nil
bin = File.read(f)                  # bin = File.read(nil)   BOOM
```

Here is a refactoring of your code:

```
...
f = ARGV[0]
abort "filename required" unless f
bin = File.read(f)
...
```

---

These changes accomplish two things:

1. When the script is invoked without the required filename, it will gracefully abort with an explanation of the problem.
2. Simplifies the code by removing `unless ARGV[0].nil?` which doesn't do anything useful will be misleading to anyone maintaining your code in the future, including yourself

Comment: Thanks Jim. I end up with no changes made to the script and instead I've run it with the correct argument like ./test.rb "filename.bin"